# How to Uninstall the Django-admin from Windows

Tags: python, django

By mistake, I installed Django-admin to my Windows instead of Virtualenv. Can anyone help me uninstalling this Django_admin from Windows?[This is the version of Django-admin installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf4Xz.png)

Comment: There's no such package named django-admin. That's django package. If you want to uninstall it, just run pip uninstall django, and then install it in virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean django package?

---

**solution 1**:
go to following path :

```
c:\users\your-username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
```

and then remove django package

**solution 2:**
Open terminal and run the following command:
*`pip uninstall django`*